# Configuring Cisco ASA to access internal websites with different domains

Tags: firewall, cisco, nat, cisco-asa, loopback

I can access www.foo.com because my AD domain is foo.com and the webserver's name on the domain is www.

I want to access www.bar.com and www.bar-foo.us and whatever alter ego my webserver wants (all on same web server).

Everything is accessible from outside of the firewall, (Port 80 and 443 are forwarded there).  But nothing but http://www.foo.com and https://www.foo.com is accessible from inside.

What sort of a rule do I need to apply?

(An awesome answer would explain using ASDM, not just command line. I'm not an idiot, I'm a programmer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

googled "dns doctoring two nat interfaces" (after an hour of looking at doctoring three NAT interfaces, not that I have three NAT interfaces)

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a00807968d1.shtml

This command really did it
static (inside,inside) 172.20.1.10 192.168.100.10 netmask 255.255.255.255

And if anyone can tell me what to click on to do it through the ASDM so I can explain it to the guy sitting next to me who administers our network, I'd give them ultimate props.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at : [Unable to connect on natted server from a host computer on the same LAN using public IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/26845/unable-to-connect-on-natted-server-from-a-host-computer-on-the-same-lan-using-pub)[link text](https://serverfault.com/questions/26845/unable-to-connect-on-natted-server-from-a-host-computer-on-the-same-lan-using-pub)