# Cisco Router - Accessing own external IP internaly

Tags: networking, cisco

**Background:**

We are a small IT company that doesnt have any official cisco training that have picked up a few cisco routers than we have been able to bluff through except for this problem.

**The issue:**

When on the internal network behind the cisco router if you try to access a service from our network using the external IP address it will not connect.

**An Example:**

If we try to visit the company website which is internally hosted then it will give an error saying it cannot estrablish a connection to the webserver.

Comment: An external service running on the router? Or some other host on the other subnet?

Comment: The host is on the same subnet so it can be accessed localy, we could easily get around it by browsing straigt to somthing but it would be good to unserstand why its happening :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using NAT ? In this case please see : [Unable to connect on natted server from a host computer on the same LAN using public IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/26845/unable-to-connect-on-natted-server-from-a-host-computer-on-the-same-lan-using-pub/26851#26851)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would be to have different internal and external DNS servers. With the external DNS having a minimal amount of published information and the internal servers having a full view. When you do this you could make the service have the internal address on the internal DNS and the external address on the external DNS.

Googling [Split DNS](http://www.isaserver.org/tutorials/You_Need_to_Create_a_Split_DNS.html) will find some useful documents